# retrieve data at specific loop values

Tags: matlab, simulation

I was wondering how i could achieve the following: I have a vector (scalar) called TimeSteps. TimeSteps increments according to the length of a vector (nBins_max) which will normally be set at a fixed length (but i may change it occasionally).
To declare a 5 full system rotations i would use:

```
TimeSteps = 5*nBins_max;
```

I would like to retrieve data for each rotation of my system. in pseduo-code i'm looking to achieve something like the following:

```
where TimeSteps = each multiple of nBins_max
retrieve data
end
```

I could set this manually at each number of timesteps i'm interested in, however, due to the number of rollers in some of my systems this could prove to be tedious and potentially error prone! Also, timesteps varies considerably in it's range, sometimes 1*nBins_max, sometimes 1000*nBins_max, perhaps more than this!

Any pointers or general help is appreciated!
Thanks for reading

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus is zero at each multiple of nBins_max:

```
where mod(TimeSteps, nBins_max)==0
    retrieve data
end
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: yes indeed it does! i hadn't considered that, guess my theory is a little rusty! thanks again, richard